# how to use <h1> in c3.js div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

I want to know about how to use any other tag in c3 chart.  for example C3 chart `<div>` is

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

**script for chart**

```
    <script>
      var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ]
    }
});
  </script>
```

this code got output perfectly. but i need to use any a `<h1>` in the  `<div id="chart"></div>` 
if i use like this

```
<div id="chart"> 
<h1>title</h1>
<p>mr.admin your daily chart </p>
</div>
```

it's not visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the library you're using but it seems that the chart needs an empty element, otherwise it won't know where to position the chart before/after the inner elements.

I suggest doing this instead:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>mr.admin your daily chart </p>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you  it's work. but i need any possible to use in side of the <div>

Answer (score 0):

You can not use  tag like inside div id with chart, because C3.js replace all the content of div with generated chart.

So, if want to use or display title then there is other way to do.

```
<div>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>mr.admin your daily chart </p>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```